# Detect country and language of the user's location offline

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an application in JavaScript and I need to determine the country and the language of the user's location based on latitude/longitude.

It's easy if I use a remote API as the Google Maps API, but how can I do it without it? Just with the latitude and longitude?

```
var lat = 48.8534100;
var lng = 2.3488000;

// Get the country from lat, lng

// Then, get the language of the country
```

This application will be used in travel. That's why. Then, get the visited country and its language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) [API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6) to get a set of country polygons. Store those in a database or file for offline local access. Query them offline.

After appropriate [polygon resolution reduction](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/simplifying-polygons.shtml) on the country polygons — some of them may have borders much more detailed than you'll need — a simple linear run through all of the countries' polygons, doing a [polygon-contains-point test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) for each one, should be plenty fast enough.

I've worked with OpenStreetMap before — it's really easy to extract the data you want.

Comment: Maybe it's a solution but I dont really want to store all of these in a database etc. Is there an quickest way ?

Comment: @Scofred: No, you need those polygons. It’s plenty quick.

Comment: @Scofred The size of all of those polygons will be kilobytes. Maybe "database" was too scary a word. Serialize them in a file however you want and then deserialize them from the file whenever you want to use them.